# PHPExcel cell style formatting error on a non-object

Tags: php, phpexcel, cell-formatting

I'm trying to format cell in my xls output sheet but when I'm trying to use

```
$xls->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_WHITE);
```

or any other method with `getStyle()` I'm getting this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getNumberFormat() on a non-object in "..."/Worksheet.php in line 755

Other `getActiveSheet()` methods like `setTitle()` or `getColumnDimension()` are working fine. I'm using Excel5 writer, but when I tried Excel2007 I got the same error. Anyone know what might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

When I comment out the column width loop I don't get the error, but the style applying still doesn't work. Column width loop works perfectly without style applying code.

Comment: are you sure that the style gives you the error? The warning is about getNumberFormat(). Try commenting this line of code, are you getting again the same error?

Comment: yes i'm sure, it works fine whne the line is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to add style to your PHPExcel.

First create a array with the styles. 
Something like this

```
    $color = array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'A5A5A5')
        ),
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
            )
        ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
    );
```

After creating the array you have to apply the styles to your object.
Something like this.

```
    $xls->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A10')->applyFromArray($color);
```

Comment: I tried all (I think all, arraystyle also) style applying methods, in every case `getStyle()` is causing the same error.

Comment: $objReader is not a object. From where you have refer this code?

Comment: $objReader is object(PHPExcel_Reader_CSV) loading data from CSV, sorry but i don't understand your question :(

Comment: when i commented out the column width setting loop  i didn't get the error but the style still wasn't applied.

Comment: Comment that line and apply my answers instead of your code

Comment: I did, and it works as I wrote, without loop no error but styling still not applied.

Comment: What column have you include in your getStyle()?

Comment: `$xls->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A3')->applyFromArray($color);` for instance, already tried just one cell like 'A1', nothing works